# Container exits even though it was started using -dit

Tags: docker

I have learnt that if I want a container to stay alive even though no process is run in the foreground (basically make bash run in foreground) I have to `docker run -dit <image_name>`.

Oddly enough, I am launching a container that way exactly, but it exists immediately.

What am I doing wrong?

The image is [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/islandsound/vowpal_wabbit/).
I start it using `docker run --name my_container -dit islandsound/vowpal_wabbit` and I want it to keep running until I stop it.

Comment: doesn't work, still exits

Comment: Now it works (after you've edited the answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image has a default process (entrypoint) which is why you need to use:

```
docker run --rm --name my_container -it --entrypoint "/bin/bash" islandsound/vowpal_wabbit
```

(Otherwise you would use `-it` with a *command* like `/bin/bash` at the end.)

Also, you usually wouldn't use `d` (which runs the container in background) if you want an interactive session.

Comment: And for the `--rm` a container used this way usually doesn't do you much good once you quit, so it's a good idea, as mentioned, in these cases to use it so you don't leave cruft behind. The container is going to be created almost instantly, so if you really had some reason to keep it running, then you could put it in the background and connect via `docker exec -ti ...`

Answer (score 1):

A Docker container *always* requires a process to be running in the foreground, otherwise the container will exit. No manner of options will change that.

The options `-dit` control Docker and how it sets up the process but it's purely down to the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` in the Dockerfile (or overrides on the command line) that control if the image stays running.

- `-d` Detaches your screen from the container and allows it to run in the background. This doesn't keep a process in the container running though.
- `-i` Keeps standard input open, sometimes required to run processes that expect someone to run it and use a keyboard and the like.
- `-t` Assigns a pseudo tty to the process, like your terminal.

`docker run -dit ubuntu` is a trick often used on images that run interactive shells like `bash` to keep them running in the background so you can `attach` or `exec` things in them.

From [the image description](https://hub.docker.com/r/islandsound/vowpal_wabbit/) it looks like you need to supply the options `--daemon --foreground` when running the image to keep the process running in the foreground.

Comment: I understand that, but regardless of the command he suggests to run, I know that `-dit` is a generic way (agnostic to the image contents) to keep a container up by putting the bash process in the foreground (correct me if I'm wrong). So what doesn't it work in this case ?

Comment: `-dit` is not really an agnostic way to keep a container running, it works for os images like `debian`/`ubuntu` which default to run a shell process in the foreground.  But the only thing keeping the container running is the process in the container.

Comment: So why wouldn't it stay on the foreground using `-dit` in this case? It is started from `ubuntu:16.04`

Comment: I can't see the Dockerfile but they will execute the `vowpal_wabbit` command (whatever that is) by default for you and then pass any options on.  This command appears to need a `--foreground` option to run in the foreground. I guess it exits without it? check `docker logs` on the exited container

Comment: I assume the process daemonizes itself by default, but it is necessary for the process to be running in the foreground in order for the container to be up. That's why you can see author uses the `--foreground` switch in the image's description.

Comment: The additional `--daemon` option gave me some doubts

Comment: I've +1 for pointing out the connection between --entrypoint and -dit. I've accepted the other answer which solved the problem. Thanks for clarifying though

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to complete Matt's excellent answer. Think of a Docker container as a Linux process, because in fact it is this way. By executing `docker run ...` you are starting a Docker process. If it quits (or starts working in the background as a deamon) the container is stopped. The process needs to run (in foreground) in order for container to be up, simple as that.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I don't want to use `--rm` because I want to reuse the same container over and over again. The problem is that I can't get it to stay up, using `-dit` as it won't put bash in the foreground

Comment: You can't reuse a container. You can run it again (new instance) though having same volumes. Or use `docker-compose`.

Comment: By reusing I mean using `start` and `stop` to manage its life, without the need to `docker run` again

Comment: Right I get it, I removed the side note.